# XPath query for node names matching a certain pattern

Tags: xpath

Is there a way to apply XPath's `starts-with` function to a node's name instead of its value? I want to select the `FOObar` and `FOObaz` nodes from the following XML document without selecting the `notFOO` node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<RootNode>
    <FOObar xmlns="http://sample.example.com">
        <value>numOne</value>
    </FOObar>
    <FOObaz xmlns="http://sample.example.com">
        <value>numTwo</value>
    </FOObaz>
    <notFOO xmlns="http://sample.example.com">
        <value>numThree</value>
    </notFOO>
</RootNode>
```

I get that it's possible to use `starts-with` to search based on text nodes, e.g.

```
//sample:value[starts-with(.,'num')]
```

Is there a way to write the following that is syntactically valid?

```
//sample:[starts-with(node(),'FOO')]
```

*This question originally came with an SSCCE, but now that the question is answered, all that code is just clutter. It's still available in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9167369/revisions), of course.*

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the `name()` or `local-name()` functions to refer to nodes by name:

```
//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'FOO')]
```

Comment: Ah, I've been looking for something like `local-name()` for hours. I was beginning to think that no such function existed. FYI for future visitors, this answer is namespace-compatible: `//sample:*[starts-with(local-name(), 'FOO')]`