# can anyone help me get this xml edit working?

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying making a NDS Wiiu VC Injector (it injects nds games into wiiu vc) and I am trying to edit the XML long and short names, but it doesnt work, it doesn't write stuff into that file.

This is a part of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu type="complex" access="777">
    <invisible_flag type="hexBinary" length="4">00000000</invisible_flag>
    <reserved_flag0 type="hexBinary" length="4">00010001</reserved_flag0>
    <reserved_flag1 type="hexBinary" length="4">00000000</reserved_flag1>
    <reserved_flag2 type="hexBinary" length="4">00000000</reserved_flag2>
    <reserved_flag3 type="hexBinary" length="4">00000000</reserved_flag3>
    <reserved_flag4 type="hexBinary" length="4">00000000</reserved_flag4>
    <reserved_flag5 type="hexBinary" length="4">00000000</reserved_flag5>
    <reserved_flag6 type="hexBinary" length="4">00000003</reserved_flag6>
    <reserved_flag7 type="hexBinary" length="4">00000001</reserved_flag7>
    <longname_ja type="string" length="512">
    </longname_ja>
    <longname_en type="string" length="512">WarioWare: Touched!</longname_en>
    <longname_fr type="string" length="512">WarioWare: Touched!</longname_fr>
    <longname_de type="string" length="512">WarioWare: Touched!</longname_de>
    <longname_it type="string" length="512">WarioWare: Touched!</longname_it>
    <longname_es type="string" length="512">WarioWare: Touched!</longname_es>
```

This is the code I am using:

```
string xmlFile = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
    )
    , @"TOOLS\EDIT\meta.xml"
);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlFile);

string newValue = textBox5.Text;

XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("//@*"); // Forgot the slashes here...
IEnumerable<XmlNode> filteredList = list.Cast<XmlNode>().
    Where(item => item.Name.ToLower().Contains("longname")); // Name property instead of Value

 foreach (XmlNode n in filteredList)
 {
     n.Value = newValue; // Setting the value.
 }

 doc.Save(xmlFile);
```

Comment: 1) What is the error? 2) What have you already tried? We are not a code writing service, please update your question so we can better help; thank you!

Comment: Can you post the XML?

Comment: paraphrasing errormessages is a bad idea. Put the exact message into your question. With stacktrace if sensible..

Comment: give me a few seconds and I'll add a part of the xml code and the error message, cause i dont know if I am allowed to share the full xml by nintendo

Comment: edited the op now

Answer (score 0):

Your Xpath query at `XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("//@*");` may be incorrect.

The following code should works:

```
XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("//*[starts-with(name(), 'longname')]");
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list[i].Name); // longname_it, longname_es, ...
    /*
    Do your stuff here...
    */
}
```

Reference: [XPath query for node names matching a certain pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167369/xpath-query-for-node-names-matching-a-certain-pattern)