# XQuery - Get nodes from parent matching given pattern

Tags: xpath, xquery

I want to filter child nodes of an XML node depending on a given pattern.

**My XML**

```
<parent>
  <total1>10</total1>
  <total2>15</total2>
  <value1>1</value1>
  <value2>2</value2>
</parent>
```

**Filter node matching this given pattern**

```
total*
```

**Expected result**

```
<parent>
  <total1>10</total1>
  <total2>15</total2>
</parent>
```

I tried to work with this xQuery but it doesn't work. I don't know what is the best way to deal with that

```
for $n in //parent/*[starts-with(.,total)]
return $n
```

Also, I would like to be able to display in output something like that

```
<total1>number(10)</total1>
<total2>number(15)</total2>
```

in the output, to convert the node value from string to number. `number(10)` come from `number(text())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath query for node names matching a certain pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167369/xpath-query-for-node-names-matching-a-certain-pattern)

Comment: *"...I would like to be able to display number(text()) in the output.."*  So what's wrong with `return $n/number(text())` ?

Comment: It is because I want to keep node name (I will update my question)

Comment: `return ($n/name(), $n/number(text()))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two little corrections:

- You’ll need to check the name of the element; otherwise, it will be checked if the string value of the element will start with the given substring.
- `total` needs to be quoted; otherwise, it will be treated as XPath expression.

Here is the result:

```
for $n in //parent/*[starts-with(name(), 'total')]
return $n
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to separate name and value in the output ? I would like to display `number(text())` as node value

Comment: It’s all possible with XQuery; but I recommend you to open a new StackOverflow question for that, or (even better) browse for answers from other users first.

Comment: I didn't find entire answers on SO, I will open a new questions